# Firebase strange behavior. Stopped accessing the network

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Trying to retrieve data from Firebase DB, all is worked fine, then after couple of requests I saw strange logs and no data being retrieved anymore, Firebase event doesn't call the network I see it in logcat.

Here is full log. I am using Firebase 11.0.2

```
07-14 10:22:58.933 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=session_start(_s),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2277481415355967345}]
07-14 10:22:58.936 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: session_start(_s), 53
07-14 10:22:58.936 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.contentoffice', name='session_start(_s)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2277481415355967345}]}
07-14 10:22:58.938 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 456
07-14 10:22:58.939 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
07-14 10:22:58.940 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
07-14 10:22:58.940 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
07-14 10:22:58.940 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 7
07-14 10:22:59.400 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Sending upload intent from DelayedRunnable
07-14 10:22:59.403 2462-2462/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Device receiver got: com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
07-14 10:22:59.407 2462-2462/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService is starting up
07-14 10:22:59.408 2462-2462/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService called. startId, action: 1, com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
07-14 10:22:59.410 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10015
07-14 10:22:59.411 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Fetching remote configuration: com.contentoffice
07-14 10:22:59.411 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, false, false
07-14 10:22:59.537 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: onConfigFetched. Response size: 0
07-14 10:22:59.539 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Successfully fetched config. Got network response. code, size: 304, 0
07-14 10:22:59.547 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Saving bundle, size: 458
07-14 10:22:59.547 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10147
07-14 10:22:59.550 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.contentoffice, 586, 
                                                               batch {
                                                                 bundle {
                                                                   protocol_version: 1
                                                                   platform: android
                                                                   gmp_version: 11020
                                                                   uploading_gmp_version: 11055
                                                                   config_version: 1499088177858764
                                                                   gmp_app_id: 1:338872414290:android:1cfea40718f29dbd
                                                                   app_id: com.contentoffice
                                                                   app_version: 1.0
                                                                   app_version_major: 1
                                                                   firebase_instance_id: cAtrMCzM1uc
                                                                   dev_cert_hash: -3540713154163920889
                                                                   app_store: manual_install
                                                                   upload_timestamp_millis: 1499998979541
                                                                   start_timestamp_millis: 1499998968774
                                                                   end_timestamp_millis: 1499998978912
                                                                   app_instance_id: 071025213b0f2723ab50b3f71036b979
                                                                   resettable_device_id: c3085378-5d4c-4053-a8dd-99d8139c7b36
                                                                   limited_ad_tracking: false
                                                                   os_version: 7.1.1
                                                                   device_model: Android SDK built for x86
                                                                   user_default_language: en-us
                                                                   time_zone_offset_minutes: 480
                                                                   bundle_sequential_index: 1
                                                                   service_upload: true
                                                                   user_property {
                                                                     set_timestamp_millis: 1499998968774
                                                                     name: first_open_time(_fot)
                                                                     int_value: 1500001200000
                                                                   }
                                                                   user_property {
                                                                     set_timestamp_millis: 1499998968774
                                                                     name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
                                                                     int_value: 1
                                                                   }
                                                                   event {
                                                                     name: first_open(_f)
                                                                     timestamp_millis: 1499998968774
                                                                     previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_conversion(_c)
                                                                       int_value: 1
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                                       string_value: auto
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: _r
                                                                       int_value: 1
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: previous_first_open_count(_pfo)
                                                                       int_value: 6
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: system_app(_sys)
                                                                       int_value: 0
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: update_with_analytics(_uwa)
                                                                       int_value: 0
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: system_app_update(_sysu)
                                                                       int_value: 0
                                                                     }
                                                                   }
                                                                   event {
                                                                     name: user_engagement(_e)
                                                                     timestamp_millis: 1499998968774
                                                                     previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                                       string_value: auto
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
                                                                       int_value: 1
                                                                     }
                                                                   }
                                                                   event {
                                                                     name: screen_view(_vs)
                                                                     timestamp_millis: 1499998968911
                                                                     previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                                       string_value: auto
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_screen_class(_sc)
                                                                       string_value: MainActivity
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_screen_id(_si)
                                                                       int_value: -2277481415355967345
                                                                     }
                                                                   }
                                                                   event {
                                                                     name: session_start(_s)
                                                                     timestamp_millis: 1499998978912
                                                                     previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                                       string_value: auto
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_screen_class(_sc)
                                                                       string_value: MainActivity
                                                                     }
                                                                     param {
                                                                       name: firebase_screen_id(_si)
                                                                       int_value: -2277481415355967345
                                                                     }
                                                                   }
                                                                 }
                                                               }
07-14 10:22:59.550 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, true, false
07-14 10:22:59.552 2462-16500/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. size: 472
07-14 10:22:59.558 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
07-14 10:22:59.662 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599994
07-14 10:22:59.664 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
07-14 10:22:59.664 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
07-14 10:22:59.667 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
07-14 10:22:59.675 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
07-14 10:22:59.676 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
07-14 10:22:59.677 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Stopping uploading service(s)
07-14 10:22:59.678 2462-16349/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService processed last upload request. StartId: 1
07-14 10:22:59.678 2462-2462/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService is shutting down
07-14 10:23:00.022 1792-2032/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fee93e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x90f44540)
07-14 10:23:03.567 2170-15958/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher I/ClearcutLoggerApiImpl: disconnect managed GoogleApiClient
07-14 10:23:03.939 16294-16330/com.contentoffice V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Here is what am I doing to call Firebase

```
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("posts").child("collection").limitToLast(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you install Google Play Services to your emulator?If yes, restart emulator and Android Studio than try again.Sometimes i get errors like this.

Comment: It worked before, but without changing the code it stopped working. Google Api's is installed on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like its a firebase migration issue reported here as well :

> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1944